# Endpoint name in project deployed on Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm using `Service Fabric` as a container for deploying existing executables.

I intend to spawn a listener on the endpoint configured at deployment time, is it possible to get the endpoint settings somehow from the context? I know that using the Stateful/stateless/actor boilerplate type of projects allow the retrieval of `CodePackageActivationContext`, but how about a basic console project deployed as an exe?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the activation context using `FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext()`

Comment: In order to get the private IP of the hosting node: FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN (this will only work if the PlatformTarget of the project is set to x64)